# How to register a mesos-slave with docker containerizer option?

Tags: docker, mesos

I have a mesos master running at IP

```
192.168.99.100:5050
```

I would like to register my mesos-slave.

However, from my mesos-slave machine when I run following command

```
./mesos-slave.sh --master=192.168.99.100:5050
```

I get error

```
    I1017 21:47:20.751700   594 main.cpp:190] Build: 2015-10-16 08:02:34 by
    I1017 21:47:20.756986   594 main.cpp:192] Version: 0.26.0
    I1017 21:47:20.757683   594 main.cpp:199] Git SHA: 6d90b3b926f3eabbec4f9e2ff627a3eeae368d84
    I1017 21:47:20.878522   594 containerizer.cpp:143] Using isolation: posix/cpu,posix/mem,filesystem/posix
    Failed to create a containerizer: Could not create MesosContainerizer: Failed to create launcher: Failed to create Linux launcher: Failed to create root cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos: Failed to create directory '/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos': Read-only file system**strong text**
```

1. Could I start my mesos-slave with docker as the containerizer?
2. How could I do it?

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE - Make sure docker is installed on the mesos-slave

1. Yes you can start your mesos-slave with docker as the containerizer.
2. Following is how to do it

> `./mesos-slave.sh --master=192.168.99.100:5050 --containerizers=docker`

Comment: and what if mesos-slave is a Docker container?

Comment: In this case, I think you must use --privileged flag in docker run